# How to Populate new field using expression containing MAX value from another field in ArcGIS attribute table using field calculator?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I've got one field `X` with 10 numerical attributes (float/double).

I've created a new field `Y` (also float/double) which I need to populate with the percentage of each record/attribute (in each of the 10 rows) relative to the MAX value in field `X`, i.e. something like `Y=X/max(!X!)`.

I need to do this using the field calculator - in VB script or Python.

Any suggestions? I thought using `max` before the field name would suffice? (I assumed it was a built-in-function from Python in ArcGIS).

Comment: Please show your code and explain what isn't working as you expected. Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: If I use the code above with Python script Y=!X!/max(!X!) it gives me 1 as the result for all the fields as it replaces !X! with the numerical value for each respective row (basically dividing with itself rather than using the max value in field X as the denominator.

Comment: If I use VB Script it throws an error saying "There was a failure during processing, check the Geoprocessing Results window for details" (i.e. Error 999999 Error exectuing function). I've tried adding commas - different sorts -, checking spaces etc. Nothing works.

Comment: Eventually I resorted to looking for the max value by ascending the values in field X and using that value to the denominator in the field calculator. However, I would still like to find out whether it would be possible for the field calculator to populate a field automatically by searching the cursor for the max value (I know this is possible when looking for max values in multiple fields, but can't find the same for a single field)

Comment: I am a beginner in python. For calculating maximum value from numeric field I need use this part of code: maximum = max(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['X'])) But after insertion into the field calculator an error message appears. In field calculator I chose python parser. Any solution? Thank you

Comment: with fieldcalculator "phyton" and show codeblock maximum = max(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['X'])) with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['X','Y']) as cursor: for row in cursor: row[1] = row[0] / maximum cursor.updateRow(row) **notif geoprocessing result :
"NameEror : name 'Y' is not defined** PLEASE HELP THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the field calculator to find the maximum value within all of the rows in a field.  However, the field calculator can perform operations horizontally, among rows using functions like `max([!field1!, !field2!, !field3!])`.

The only way to accomplish this is by using cursors outside of the field calculator.  Try the following workflow:

Use a generator to list all of the row values in `X` and find the list max

```
maximum = max(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['X']))
```

Then loop through each row and perform the calculations:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['X','Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0] / maximum
```

--

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\featureclass'

maximum = max(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['X']))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['X','Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0] / maximum
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I suspected this was the case (not able to find the max value horizontally); your solution works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray in the Field calculator using Python. It first creates an Array (list) of all the 'X' values. Afterwards the max value is calculated and given a seperate variable. Last step is to divide this maxium value from each 'Y' value ('Scores', in my example below).

```
def my_rank(score_value):
    my_list = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray ("Rank_test", "Scores")
    my_max = my_list["Scores"].max()
    ranking_score = score_value / my_max 
    return ranking_score
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment. this works great also, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other more direct way you could create an empty list and populate it with x field, maximum in a list is then easily found and used to populate the y fields.